# Nameserver not responding

Tags: server, dns, bind, vps

I setup the dns on vps completely but i am getting error as follows as per intodns.com

ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
8.33.137.137

I am using ubuntu 14.04Lts

Please help me out. How i can resolve this issue??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the server by IP? by its fully qualified name of sdns1.ovh.ca?

If you can, then you have to give more information on your server setup.

Can you clarify what type of DNS setup you have configured?  Cached, primary master or secondary master?  if cached, what have you setup in your /etc/bind/named.conf.options file? If primary, what have you set in in your forward and reverse zone files? etc.

Comment: Primary nameserver is fine. I am getting the problem with secondary slave nameserver and sdns1.ovh.ca is my secondary nameserver.  I can also able to ping by ip and by FQDN sdns1.ovh.ca